# Why does Spring Controller not return Last-Modified header?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a simple controller (some of the code has been removed for readability but the general gist is that I am adding the `Last-Modified` header to the response):

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/{s}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<DetailsDto> getSaleDetails(
        @RequestHeader(name = "If-Modified-Since", required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime ifModifiedSince) {
    final ResponseEntity<DetailsDto> response;
        response = ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Cache-Control", "private")
                .header("Last-Modified", "ekofnef") //I have tried with valid dates by the way
                .body(returnThisBody());
    return response;
}
```

And I have the following test:

```
    @Test
void testHeader() throws Exception {

    MvcResult responseFromRequest = mockMvc.perform(get(uri())
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

    assertThat(responseFromRequest.getResponse().getStatus(), is(equalTo(OK.value())));
    assertThat(responseFromRequest.getResponse().getContentAsString() != null, is(equalTo(true)));

    assertThat(responseFromRequest.getResponse().getHeader("Last-Modified"), is(notNullValue()));
}
```

The test does call the endpoint and but fails on the assertion where it checks that the Last-Modified header is not null. I have debugged it and can see that the headers are indeed populated when the controller is returning the response. I can see my `Cache-Control` and `Last-Modified` headers populated. But when the response comes into the test and I debug the `responseFromRequest` variable, I can only see the `Cache-Control` header and not the `Last-Modified` header... I'm not sure why.

Is the `Last-Modified` header something special in that i have to configure spring to facilitate it?

EDIT = I have noticed that the test passes when the date is formated `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` standard.. why does it not work with `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`?

Answer (score 0):

Spring `ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder` interface extends [`ResponseEntity.HeadersBuilder<ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.HeadersBuilder.html), which has specific methods to deal with `Last-Modified` header: [`lastModified(long lastModified)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.HeadersBuilder.html#lastModified-long-) and [`B lastModified(Instant lastModified)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.HeadersBuilder.html#lastModified-java.time.Instant-) and [`B lastModified(ZonedDateTime lastModified)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.HeadersBuilder.html#lastModified-java.time.ZonedDateTime-)

Use one of these to set the `Last-Modified` header:

```
response = ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Cache-Control", "private")
                .lastModified(getResourceLastModifiedDate())
                .body(returnThisBody());
```

**Why?**

The mentioned `lastModified` methods handle proper date-time format. The `Last-Modified` header requires a valid [RFC 1123 Time Format](https://wiki.freepascal.org/RFC_1123_Time_Format) and the `lastModified` methods handle this for you.

You can test it out by manually setting an example value to your code:

```
response = ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Last-Modified", "Sun, 21 Oct 2018 12:16:24 GMT")
                .body(returnThisBody());
```

The above will work because the value is a valid RFC 1123 Time Format, but, as I said, maybe it's better to use the `lastModified` methods, because they already handle the proper format without any more code in your side.

Comment: Why would this result in different behavior in their test? What was wrong with their implementation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis . . . the lastModified methods handle proper datetime format. That's why his implementation is not working. `Last-Modified` header expects a RFC 1123 Time Format. If the value does not meet this requirement, the header is omitted. Answer updated with explanation . . . I appreciate if you can review your downvote.

Comment: Can you also please explain why the header was stripped from the response?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis . . . I don't know the specific component that does this. My best guess is: **if it is a Spring behavior**, then it must be a filter or a interceptor . . .